# Css3 select all input fields residing in a class but not ones containing a specific data attr not working

Tags: css

I have an issue with my CSS3 selection. I have a table, inside the table are input elements (text) 3 for each row. Each one in that row containing a specific data-attr. Now I have a css selection for selecting all but ones containing the data-attr labeled data-sl="inputs-calc-sub-label" and data-sl="inputs-calc-add-label" (for now) I am just trying to change the background. But here is my selection

```
.getLength > input:not([data-sl='inputs-calc-sub-label'])
```

But it applies styles to all elements. Again I want to ignore the input with that data-attr. How can I do this? What am I doing wrong? I am working on the latest version of chrome right now. Maybe the version before. Can someone help me with this? All I want to do is select all but the ones containing the data-attr.

Comment: Figured it out using .container td > input:not(:first-child) instead

Comment: But why could I not do it with a data-attr?

Comment: i have a javascript alternative if you want ?

Answer (score 0):

We can't really help without seeing your corresponding html to this css, however I think the problem is with the css selector you are using.

The element>element selector is used to select elements with a specific parent.

Note: Elements that are not directly a child of the specified parent, are not selected.

therefore in your example 
the .getLength must have a direct child of input

```
    <td class="getLength"><input type="text" data-attr="normal"</td>
```

here's a fiddle for more help

https://jsfiddle.net/7s1nbarh/1/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.getLength:not([data-sl='inputs-calc-sub-label']) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

input {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<input class="getLength"/>
<input class="getLength" data-sl='inputs-calc-sub-label'/>
```

If you want to keep the inputs the way they are, without adding in unnecessary parent elements, simply change the CSS selector to act directly upon the elements of the class, and not their children.